# Split a string (that contains tags) by spaces without breaking the tags or tag inner html in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm attempting to split a string by spaces into an array of words. If the string contains HTML tags, I would like the full tag (including content) to be treated as a single word.

For example,

```
I like to eat <a href="http://www.waffles.com/">tasty delicious waffles</a> for breakfast
```

should split into

```
I
like
to
eat
<a href="http://www.waffles.com/">tasty delicious waffles</a>
for
breakfast
```

I've seen a couple related threads on Stack Overflow but I'm having trouble adapting anything to Javascript because they were written for languages that I'm not quite familiar with. Is there a regex expression that could easily do this or will the solution require multiple regex splits and iteration?

Thanks.

Comment: Can there be nested tags like `<div> foo <div> bar </div> baz </div>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
result = subject.match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/g);
```

will work if your tags can't be nested, if all tags are properly closed, and if current tag names don't occur in comments, strings etc.

**Explanation:**

```
<\s*            # Either match a < (+ optional whitespace)
(\w+\b)         # tag name
(?:             # Then match...
 (?!            # (as long as it's impossible to match...
  <\s*\/\s*\1\b # the closing tag here
 )              # End of negative lookahead)
 [\s\S]         # ...any character
)*              # zero or more times.
<\s*\/\s*\1\s*> # Then match the closing tag.
|               # OR:
\S+             # Match a run of non-whitespace characters.
```

Comment: This splits the tag in-between if tag has attributes.

Comment: @Rajesh: I don’t see how, can you give an example?

Comment: I would like to correct myself. This breaks the html tags which are self closing like <img /> and <br /> etc. Link to test: https://regex101.com/r/TU1NJ2/2

Comment: @Rajesh: Ah yes, I see. I should update this. In your example, the `<img>` tag is not self-closed (which seems to have been standard in earlier HTML versions). Should this case be considered as well or should we expect `<img>` tags to be self-closed? If the former: are there other tags like that?

Comment: We should not assume them to be self closed. People still use <br> tag without closing. So, I can think of a few: link, br, img

Comment: If that list is exhaustive, it would be possible to adjust the regex. But on the other hand, people also use `<p>` (and probably others) without closing, and we can't accept those. The longer I think about this, the clearer it becomes that this problem can only be solved with a proper parser. The restrictions imposed by regex are too big considering not only malformed input, but also nesting of tags which is of course allowed but unsupported in JavaScript regex...

Answer (score 1):

This is hard or impossible to do with regexp alone (depending on the complexity of HTML that you want/need to allow).

Instead, iterate over the children of the parent node and split them if they are text nodes or print them unmodified if they are non-text nodes.