# What's the quickest way to truncate paragraph text that may or may not include HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to truncate paragraph text that may or may not include HTML tags. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this with straight jQuery or vanilla javascript. You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/4BzpY/3/

```
var text = "This <a href=\"\">is</a> some text with a link";

var shortText = jQuery.trim(title).substring(0, 10).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";

alert(shortText );
```

The truncated text will be in a paragraph element that can dynamically expand to show all content. With that being the case, I don't want to strip HTML tags and then show them only when full expanded. HTML should remain as is in the collapsed and expanded states.

Comment: Is it okay if the HTML is removed?

Comment: No, because it would need to be there when the paragraph is expanded

Comment: You have an error in JSFiddle. Change `title` to `text`

Comment: Good catch. I've added more info to the question as well.

Comment: Why don't you just make a wrapper element and change its height? http://jsfiddle.net/6qFua/

Comment: I added the answer just in case it helps someone else. This is tricky because HTML can be so complicated. What happens if you cut it off partially through a tag? All sorts of things can go wrong. You're probably looking at needing to write a complex function which removes any opening tags that end on the cut-off side of the truncation.

Comment: @Blender 's fiddle appears to work even if it cuts off some tags: http://jsfiddle.net/6qFua/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/6qFua/2/ I know it's possible to add the ellipses at the end of cut-off text with CSS, but I'm not sure how it functions for bigger truncations or what browser compatibility is.

Comment: @Blender - I'm wanting to avoid having partially hidden text show up.

Comment: @Bjork24 This seems like it could be pretty complex... If I understand what you want, you'd have to change your truncating so it only counts visible characters, and not characters that are a part of html tags, and then once you've hit your limit you'd have to close any open tags in the truncated text. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Bjork24 Your example uses jQuery 1.4.4 - can we use anything newer?

Comment: @JasonP - Yes, that's basically it

Comment: @Corion - Yes. I forked from another example.

Comment: @Bjork24 That algorithm should be doable. There could certainly be tricky edge cases depending on what elements are present (like if you had a list or table in the full html)

Comment: For a start, you will probably need to use [jQuery's parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) to get a list of HTML nodes. Then you might need to loop through them, grabbing the text length of each. When you run out of space, truncate the last text node and then add them all back to the div. You might have to skip adding the last node you find and all its parents, or skip complex nodes like tables altogether.

Answer (score 7):

If this is for display on a page, a neater way may be to use CSS. Given the HTML:

```
    <span class="truncated">this is truncated text</span>
```

and the CSS:

```
    .truncated {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

this will display something similar to:

```
    this is...
```

You can then use JavaScript to remove the CSS class when required. Sample implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/a8QK4/

Comment: How well does this work if it cuts off the middle of complex HTML tags?

Comment: @Corion It's a visual effect, so it will stop the content at the given width and append the ellipsis - whatever formatting is in place at the time.

Comment: @Bjork24 The example given was a short piece of text, so I considered it an appropriate solution. I've taken this code from an implementation that does work on Firefox, so I'll double-check to see what I may have missed off.

Comment: This works in the version of Firefox I'm using, 21.0. I've also recently used this on a live site that (I think) was tested back to IE8 and possibly IE7.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out using regex. Found the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552371/142486

```
var text = $('#my-text');
var maxWords = 25;
var words = text.html().match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/g);
text.html(words.slice(0, maxWords).join(" ") + " ...");
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/3Yjm8/

I'll simply add the unadulterated HTML to the element with `data()`, then replace it when the box is expanded.

Comment: You appear to have answered a different question to the one you originally asked. In addition, your solution only counts the number of words correctly if words are wrapped by tags individually; put a span around a group of them and it counts that span as being a single word.

Comment: This still breaks when you have something like the table in the middle :(

Comment: Adrian is right, any elements nested within each other will not be counted for example a `ul` or `ol` with listed `li`s will not be counted unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility for this kind of situation is to temporarily convert the data being truncated to text.

Send the HTML to a throwaway element and then extract the text:

```
var title = $('<div>').html(text).text();
```

`This <a href=\"\">is</a> some text with a link` becomes `This is some text with a link`, which can then be truncated safely.

If you need to expand that to the original text again, just keep a copy with the HTML still in it.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/B2AZA/

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit I added to the question, I need to maintain the same HTML in the collapsed and expanded versions.