# shrink text in table td so it fits the size. Gradually display the text on resize column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a Asp.Net MVC 4 view and now I have to create a costumer report. The data in the 'TD´s' sometimes is greater than the size of the table column.

I would like to include the '...' at the end of the word so the user is able to know that there is more information in that TR.

If the user wants to see the full text, it would resize the column as we would do in Microsoft excel and the text would appears gradually.

Is this possible to achieve with javascript?

Comment: You may be able to use CSS for this (I'm on limited time at the moment to investigate further, sorry); take a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458410/whats-the-quickest-way-to-truncate-paragraph-text-that-may-or-may-not-include-h/17458554#17458554.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much you wish to customize it you might want to use the [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin. It ahs some pretty neat extras and customizations for truncating texts and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Count the characters in the field and if greater than X display the substring 0 to X-3 concatenated with '...'

something like this:

```
var len = 10;
var field = document.getElementById("XXX");

if (field.innerText.length > len) {
  field.innerText = field.innerText.substring(0, len-3) + '...';
}
```