# Splitting sentences at spaces but not in html tags

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a senctence at the whitespaces in java. But in the text they are html tags and I don't want to split the words here.
So for example `"hello <a>John Smith</a> hey ho"` should be split as:

```
hello
<a>John Smith</a>
hey
ho
```

I thought about using split and found a regex in javascript but I couldn't convert it to java.
Is there maybe a better way then using split with a regex?

[Edit]
Here is the javascript regex I could convert but I wonder if there's a better way than a regex?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552371/2170547

Comment: You should provide the JS regex and provide what you have tried to convert it, adding some Java code would be the best. Converting a JS regex to Java should be quite easy.

Comment: What about sentences enclosed in HTML tags, e.g. `<html>hello <a>John Smith</a> hey ho</html>`?

Comment: Use an HTML parser, else [the pony, he comes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418556)..

Comment: there are only single tags with no enclosed tags

Comment: Here there be dragons. Parse it. By "dragons" I mean "ponies".

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: It's not too difficult to get a solution that will work most of the time. Messy improper HTML will always cause parser problems, but you can still just use a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some actual working Java7 code http://ideone.com/PWv56h

```
class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
     String test = "testing 1 2 3 <a title=\"a demo\" href=\"\">testing 4 5 6</a> testing\t7\n8\r9 <br /><script src=\"blah\" />more text";
     java.util.regex.Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(<(?<tag>[A-Za-z]+)[^>]*?>[^<]*</\\k<tag>>)|(<[A-Za-z]+[^>]*?/>)|([^\\p{Space}]+)").matcher(test);
     while(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
  }
}
```

The regex matches 3 separate groups

- An HTML tag with a closing tag <a blah>blah</a>
- An HTML tag with no closing tag <script src="blah" />
- A run of text with no white-space in it

If the HTML is proper and HTML entities are escaped correctly the above regex matcher should work well. Even in messy HTML it'll be quick and fairly accurate.

Comment: thanks it's working fine! Can you maybe explain "<tag>" in the regex?

Comment: @user2170547 - Sure (?<tag>...) is a "named matching group" the name being "tag", it is "back referenced" with \\k<tag> this allows the regex to match the opening A or DIV or SPAN with it's matching closing tag. The issues arise when you have tags nested inside of each other.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I do not recommend regex to parse any form of html, but if you insist, here is what you have to do:

You have to first match all html tags, then split on space. It's easier in regex to do the inverse of what you're trying to do.

Here's a live example:  http://regex101.com/r/wX5hI4

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Here is the generated java-code extracted from the website:

```
String re = "(<a>.*?</a>)\\s*| ";
String str = "hello <a>John Smith</a> hey ho";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

Comment: +1, but the Regex should likely use `.*` inside the `<>` so that other tags would work as well.

Comment: 1+ for sharing regex101.com.  that site is sick

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't work in java :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dB7zK5)

```
(?<=</(a)>)|(?=<(a)>)
```