# Javascript split() messes up my html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, split

I have a 2500-words string that I need to be put in different `DIV`. I have used the `text = text.split(' ')` function to retrieve each word and then have my `DIVs` filled until `DIV.scrollHeight` becomes higher than `DIV.offsetHeight`, then it goes to the next `DIV`.

The problem I encounter is that my HTML tags in my 2500-word string are completely messed up:
it closes my `<b>` tags where it shouldn't, doesn't display the `</b>` where it should, doesn't display the `<font` part of this tag, doesn't display the `</font>`, etc.

Any idea why?

Many thanks!

Edit: As requested, here is the entire jQuery code. Pardon me in advance for any mistake in it :)

```
function addText(texte)
   {
        // var texte = texte.replace('<', '&lt;');
        // var texte = texte.replace('>', '&gt;');
        var container = $('DIV[id^=apDiv]').find('DIV#bloc_prim');
        console.log('NOMBRE DE CONTAINER : '+container.length);
        var length = texte.length;
        console.log('LONGUEUR DU TEXTE '+length+' caractères');
        // container.html(texte);
        var hauteurDiv = container.prop('offsetHeight');
        var hauteurContent = container.prop('scrollHeight');
        length = Math.floor((length * hauteurDiv)/hauteurContent);

        console.log(hauteurContent);
        // container.html(texte.substring(0, length));
        var hauteurRestante = hauteurContent - hauteurDiv;

        console.log(hauteurRestante);

        var TABLEAU = texte.split(' ');
        // var TABLEAU = texte.match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/g);
        console.log('LONGUEUR TABLEAU : '+TABLEAU.length+' occurences');
        // console.log(TABLEAU[4]);
        i = 0;
        hauteurTotale = container.prop('scrollHeight');
        console.log(container.prop('offsetHeight'));
        console.log(hauteurTotale);
        while(i < TABLEAU.length)
        {

            while(hauteurTotale <= container.prop('offsetHeight'))
            {
                container.append(TABLEAU[i]+' ');
                i++;
                hauteurTotale = container.prop('scrollHeight');
                console.log(i+':'+hauteurTotale+' --- '+container.prop('offsetHeight'));
            }
            if(i < TABLEAU.length)
            {
                var clone = container.parent('DIV[id^=apDiv]').clone(true); // On copie la DIV
                $('BODY').append(clone); // On colle la partie copiée
                clone.find('DIV#bloc_prim').empty();
            }
            var hauteurTotale = clone.find('DIV#bloc_prim').prop('scrollHeight');
            console.log(hauteurTotale);
            while(hauteurTotale <= clone.find('DIV#bloc_prim').prop('offsetHeight'))
            {
                if(i < TABLEAU.length)
                {
                    clone.find('DIV#bloc_prim').append(TABLEAU[i]+' ');
                    i++;
                    hauteurTotale = clone.find('DIV#bloc_prim').prop('scrollHeight');
                    console.log(i+':'+hauteurTotale+' --- '+container.prop('offsetHeight'));
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        console.log(i+'->'+TABLEAU.length);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to generate the Html, as well as the Html output?

Comment: Done. The HTML output is like so:
`<b>JDLI</b> : Ellen Page, Williem Dafoe, Hans Zimmer… De tels noms n’entretiennent pas l’ambigüité avec la notion de film interactif ? 
<b>David</b> Cage : Personnellement, je n’ai jamais ressenti d’ambiguïté à ce sujet.` where `</b>` tag should be at the end of the sentence for the first line, and after `Cage` for the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat tag contents as single words you can try instead of `var TABLEAU = texte.split(' ');` to use

```
var nodes = $('<div/>',{ html: texte }).contents();
var TABLEAU = nodes.map(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 ? $(this).text().split(' ') : this;
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have used your piece of code but the `return [...] : this;` is giving me `[object HTMLBRElement]` instead of the actual `<br/>`

Comment: this happens at the place where you append due to the `.append(TABLEAU[i] + '')` that you have.. it tries to convert the element to a string.. replace them with `.append(TABLEAU[i]).append(' ');` (*it is found in two places in your code*)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be that you might be splitting tags and then the browser tries to fix it messing it all up.

With you algorithm you might end up with something like:

```
<div>
    <p>The text starts here
</div>
<div>
    and ends here</p>
</div>
```

Which is clearly not the best thing. I think you should keep track of the opening/closing tags and only change container div when they're all closed

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for answering. I'm clearly aware that I end up with some messed-up HTML. What I'm looking for is for my jQuery to treat my HTML tags as words.
I've found this question which helps a bit my problem.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551974/split-a-string-that-contains-tags-by-spaces-without-breaking-the-tags-or-tag-i)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
I used the following Regex to catch the words and HTML tags and used the following `.replace()` to add spaces after all my `<br/>` (which was the source of the problem).

• `var texte = texte.replace(/<br>/g, '<br/> ');`

• `var TABLEAU = texte.match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/gi);`

This did the trick.

Thanks all!